# zip: command not found after installing zip on NODE docker image, even after installing p7zip?

Tags: docker, gitlab, node.js, cicd

I'm trying to zip my dist folder and post to it Azure's kudu zipdeploy endpoint but I keep getting this error regardless of the fact that I have installed a zipping package myself.

My docker image: [weltn24/up-docker-node-chrome-headless](https://hub.docker.com/r/weltn24/up-docker-node-chrome-headless/tags/) on tag: chrome-66_node-10.0_yarn-1.6.0

The part that fails in my yml file:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - apt-get install p7zip p7zip-full
    - yarn install
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
    - cd dist/AngularTemplate; zip -r ../dist.zip *; cd ..; cd..
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist.zip
```

The commands on the 4'th line is failing with zip: command not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct script below:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - apt-get install zip unzip
    - yarn install
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
    - cd dist/AngularTemplate; zip -r ../../dist.zip *; cd ..; cd..
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist.zip
```

Was installing the wrong Zip package and then puttin my archive in the wrong folder.